# Navigation Android and Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I am using google navigation in my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=53.3,21.7"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is any way to open this navigation in my app with custom settings?

Comment: No it is not your app

Comment: custom settings being?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

float lat = 53.3f;
    float lng = 21.7f;

```
String maplLabel = "ABC Label";
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+lat+","+lng+"&z=16 (" + maplLabel + ")"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In this way, you open the external App maps.